# Why is my ggplot geom_tile legend going higher than I want?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, gradient, facet-grid

So I'm creating a heat map for some data and I'm making it show the volume of vehicles recorded aggregated by hour and day of week. However, when I make the map the legend seems to not work and therefore, the tiles do not go up to the "darkest red shade". Does anyone know what's going on? Thank you:

```
Hourplus <- c(Hour, Hour, Hour, Hour, Hour, Hour, Hour, Hour)
facetgrid <- data.frame(DayofWeek, Totals5, Totals6, Totals3, Totals4, Totals1, Totals2, Totals7, Totals8)
names(facetgrid) <- c("DayofWeek", "Marine Dr NB", "Marine Dr SB", "Carman NB", "Carman SB", "Glisan NB", "Glisan SB", "Stafford NB", "Stafford SB")


facetgrid <- melt(facetgrid)
facetgrid$DayofWeek <- factor(facetgrid$DayofWeek, levels=c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"))
facetgrid
levels(facetgrid$DayofWeek) <- c("M","Tu","W","Th","F","Sa","Su")
gg <- ggplot(facetgrid, aes(x=Hourplus, y=DayofWeek, fill=value)) + geom_tile(color="white", size=0.1) + facet_wrap(~variable, ncol = 2, scales='free')
gg <- gg + coord_equal()
gg <- gg + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL, title ="May 2017: Volume of Vehicles Greater than 20ft in Length")
gg <- gg + theme_tufte()
gg <- gg + theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))
gg <- gg + theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=7))
gg <- gg + theme(legend.title=element_text(size=8))
gg <- gg + theme(legend.text=element_text(size=6))
gg <- gg + scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "red", name="Volume")
gg <- gg + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,24,4), limits=c(0,25))
ggsave("8stationsvol.png", height =8, width = 12)
```

This is what the map looks like right now (none of the tiles are the darkest red)
[image: Fig]

Comment: Can I suggest switching from oldish red/white palette to `viridis`? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/viridis/vignettes/intro-to-viridis.html From `low="white"` on white background doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but my employer wants it to be like this. I'm really just trying to solve this problem at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Ggplot does add "wiggle" room for most scales of continuous nature, as with the X and Y axis.
To set strict (or custom) limits, employ the function "limits" within scale_fill_gradient. In you case, feed it a vector with lower and upper limits.

```
gg + scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",
      high = "red",
      name="Volume",
      limits = c(min(facetgrid$value), max(facetgrid$value)))
```